# Hidden-features question closed for DrRacket as 'too localised'

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

["What are the “hidden features” of the DrRacket IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181792/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-the-drracket-ide-closed) was closed as 'too localised', which surprised me as it is the IDE for popular and well regarded Lisp-family language 'Racket' previously known as PLT-Scheme.

It gets use in education and industry, and was used to implement the 'Arc' language.

The [same question for Eclipse wasn't closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886/hidden-features-of-eclipse), and while eclipse has a large Market share, Racket **is** used by significant numbers of users across the globe.

Comment: FWIW, I voted "Not a real question".

Comment: It was real enough for one of the voters to ask for it to be changed to 'community wiki'.

Comment: Community Wiki is not a free pass to avoid closing.

Comment: Wasn't suggesting CW was a free pass for anything, but why ask for it to be made CW, then vote to close as too localised? Seems a bit contradictory.

Comment: Link to the eclipse one so I can vote to close please

Comment: He could have asked for it to be CW and then come back later and decided to vote to close. Or the other way around if he thought it might not get closed.

Answer (score 6):

My vote was for "not a real question" as it has been for every one of the horrible non-questions that have "hidden features" in the title.

No matter the intent or the spirited defense that "people can learn something from this", these questions end up acting as a "favorite features" poll: a vanishing fraction of the answer are actually hidden, and most aren't even very obscure.

I'm putting a fake nose on "Hidden features" and taking it to Bedevere's scales.

Comment: That's fine, but it was voted off for 'too localised'

Comment: ...I votes for NaRQ, Shog9 voted for NoRQ, but at least two of the other closers voted for "too localized" (and got in ahead of me and Shog9 if it was only two). You'll have to ask *them* why.

Answer (score 3):

First off, these "hidden features" questions are [hardly non-controversial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52456/new-hidden-features-questions-coincidence-copycat-or-sock-puppet). In theory, you could have one posted for every single programming-related tool, technique, or abstract concept... Just because the Eclipse post managed to stay alive, do we really need to give "Hidden features of *every editor ever written including EDLIN*" a free pass as well?

Second, even the ones that *do* avoid getting closed do so by following the traditions established in the past: community-wiki, one feature per answer, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but it was closed as **too localised**, not because of the tag.

Comment: @Stephen: I can't really do more than guess at why three people voted for that reason, but I'll bet it has something to do with DrRacket being something of a niche tool compared to, say, Eclipse. Anyway, you know why me & dmckee voted now.

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen: you may not be understanding that the final close reason is chosen based on the "majority" close reason. The fact that this one was closed as "too localized" doesn't mean there were five votes to close as "too localized" - only that there were three.

In fact, I don't know what would happen if there were two votes for "too localized", and one each for "not a real question", "subjective and argumentative", and "off topic". It might still be closed as "too localized" because there were two of that close reason vs. one each of the others.

Comment: It's majority wins, so 2-1-1-1 yields the 2. In the event of a tie, the earliest vote wins. So in this particular case, "too localized" would win as long as it had at least 2 votes and dmckee and Shog9 were the only NARQ votes. Since they were last, they lose any ties.

Comment: @Grace: good point, I'd forgotten about that.