# Reviewing questions in Close queue with no effort by asker

Tags: discussion, review, close-reasons

I've been reviewing on and off for a year or 2 and the use of the **"unclear what you're asking"** flag has been bugging me for a while now. It just seems like too many sub-reasons lumped together.

As you know there are quite a few questions like:

> "I want this and that (...) and I want it to look exactly like that
>   (...) some code excerpt from a homework assignment (...) gimmeez the code now plz hurry"

According to [the accepted answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort) I should just downvote them and move on, which is fine.

When I review questions like these in the Close queue however, should I close them? I usually do, and the most appropriate reason I think according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032/151967) = **"unclear what you're asking"** flag - but that's not true. Most of the time it is blatantly obvious what they are asking, they just didn't put any effort in to asking the question.

Is this the correct reason to use?

Or would it be a good idea to specifically have a reason to address this situation? There certainly are enough questions to tag with it. Maybe something like **"You have not provided enough evidence that you have attempted a solution"** or **"Please provide steps on what you have attempted so far"**. I believe this new reason "try harder" would be less ambiguous than "its unclear".

## TLDR

What close reason to use for *Gimme codez*?

Comment: You should ask questions like these on http://meta.stackoverflow.com, not here. And it has probably been asked before.

Comment: @Glorfindel I looked for that site in the stackexchange dropdown (top left on the website) and it isn't there. I thought they'd merged it lol.

Comment: @Glorfindel over there it would likely be closed as duplicate of [Appropriate Response for 'Do My Job' Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260647/839601) or one of questions linked to it

Comment: It's unclear because "that's a lovely set of requirements you have there! Now, what's your problem?"

Answer (score 2):

Effectively this boils down to *Should I use a close reason which doesn't apply but still closes the question because I think it is bad?*

The answer is an obvious *no*. Close reasons must be used for the reason in its description only. Homework questions are on-topic if they are within the scope of the site. Not having done enough research is a valid down-vote reason, not a close vote reason. (So the answer to your question *What close reason to use for Gimme codez?* is *none*).

Often there is much more wrong with the question, so that makes it hard sometimes to choose between close reasons. Sometimes I use that reason because it is not exactly clear how the question should be applied (the question is clear on itself, but misses essential details to give a concise answer). I think it is okay to use that close reason then.