# How to raise helpful flags?

Tags: discussion, support, helpful-flags

In my profile it shows helpful flags : 6.
Clicking on it shows flagging history.

How can I raise helpful flag? What activity increase this count? How is it helpful to others?

Comment: Helpful flags are flags you have raised which the moderators evaluated as helpful.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/what-does-the-helpful-flag-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you found questions something like Spam, Duplicate, off topic, not constructive, not a real question, etc you can flag it.

If you found answers like Spam, not an answer, etc you can flag it.

If you found comments like rude or offensive, not constructive / off-topic, obsolete, too chatty, etc you can flag it

Moderators and reviewers will look at the issue and decide whether the flag was helpful or not and mark it 'helpful' or 'declined' or 'disputed'.

You can earn badges like

```
Deputy  -  Raised 80 helpful flags 
Marshal -  Raised 500 helpful flags
```

Answer (score 4):

Just flag questions as appropriate. Moderators and reviewers will look at the issue and decide whether the flag was helpful or not and mark it 'helpful' or 'declined' or 'disputed'.