# Which flagging rule apply here?

Tags: discussion, flags, helpful-flags

Generally when we flag a post (using normal or 'other' option) it is finally handled by moderator as *helpful* or *declined* (or *disputed* by 10K users). But there are few case where a flag is actually handled by OP and it always results as *helpful* flag.

Let me explain, I flag this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806839/can-we-do-android-development-in-windows-8-using-adt) (visible to 10K user). It was non programming question and after 2 downvotes OP deleted that question. Once OP deleted the question it results to me as 1 increment in my *helpful* flag.

So my question is, Here which flag rule apply that always results as *helpful* flag and never as *declined* flag ?

Comment: I think if someone voted to close/delete based on your flag, then your flag would be marked as "helpful" too.

Comment: Yes, but how come it always results same ( `helpful` ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flag is marked as "helpful" if it causes an action to be taken on a post (like closing or deleting), or if a moderator explicitly clicked the "helpful" button when processing your flag.

So in this case, since the question was deleted, your flag was marked as "helpful". It is irrelevant that the deletion was by the original poster rather than by a moderator. Similarly, your flag would have been marked as helpful if the question had been deleted by 3 20k+ users.

See also: [What does the helpful flag mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/what-does-the-helpful-flag-mean)