# Python Persecution?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Should ‘hidden features of X’ be removed/closed/locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked)

Why [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python-closed) has been closed and ...

1. [Hidden Features of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript)
2. [Hidden Features of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954327/hidden-features-of-html)
3. [Hidden features of Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161872/hidden-features-of-perl)
4. [Hidden features of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby)
5. many others ....

   are still open?

Comment: should be moved to meta.stackoverflow.com or this will get closed too :)

Comment: Don't comment on migration requests, flag instead.

Comment: also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57561/questioning-whether-question-deserved-to-be-closed

Comment: don't flag, move!

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57363/concerted-efforts-to-close-hidden-features-of-x-language-type-of-question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked. Also don't sweat it; the question will be reopened soon.

Comment: By the way, that's the worst possible argument you could make to have the question reopened...

Comment: Because Pythons are Sneaky and dangerous!

Comment: I'm not bothered half as much by all the hidden features questions as I am by all the whining that accompanies them. Whining that they should be closed, whining that they should be reopened, whining that some were closed when others weren't, whining that SO is being destroyed by people who post hidden features questions, whining that SO is being destroyed by people who close hidden features questions; it's getting **ridiculous**. We should just take a vote on whether or not these questions are OK, and enforce that across the whole site

Answer (score 3):

Because we haven't closed, and persuaded diamonds to lock, all of those yet. We're trying.