# Why was a question about suggesting syntax highlighting service/library deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

My question was the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112314/which-syntax-highlighter-with-export-to-html-for-blog-to-choose. I have not much time for SO last year or two, so I just spotted that and don't even know, when exactly the question was deleted.

As SO had a lot of questions of that kind (and still currently dozens of them), I just wanted to review and put answers in form of community wiki together into the one structurized page. Time to time, I visited it when needed, and as I can see, it was also useful to some other people.

Looking at cached version, I see: *closed as not constructive by Bill the Lizard♦ Jun 1 at 11:02*
*As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. **We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.** If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.*

Men, that's why I proposed the structure, providing: links, commentary, actual technical info. And it was fine for 19 months! There were no debates and extended discussions: [yandex cached page](https://sites.google.com/site/nakitemp/syntaxhighlighters). I don't get, why to delete it.

I don't know, what else to say. Actually the cached version is all I can provide to your review. And now, because of deletion, I have to propose *to debate, poll and discuss* here...

Comment: *deleted by casperOne♦ Aug 30 at 17:59*

Comment: We *can* discuss the reasons and such here, that's what Meta is for, and where there is a `discussion` tag. :-) 10k+ users can still see the question.

Comment: The short answer is that over time, the SO community has learned a lot about what works and what doesn't for the site, and questions like yours simply don't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, lets delete all questions, which got only <=5 upvotes and <=500 views in 1.5 year? They *don't work for the site* )

Comment: No, but do delete low-voted, low-viewcount, *closed, non-constructive* posts. Note that 10k+ users can still vote to undelete it, reversing the deletion by the moderator. I don't know if that'll happen, but the possibility exists.

Comment: ProTip: it's not a good idea to address everyone else on the Stack Exchange network of sites as "men". Believe it or not, there are some females around here...

Answer (score 9):

Sorry that you came back and had that experience.

This is a list question, and [list questions were never really accepted on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124489/140951).  I understand the close reason might be a little ambiguous, but that's the one that we use for list questions.

The question you reference is a good example of why list questions are not a good fit for the site.  I understand you haven't been on the site for the past year or two, but that question and answers haven't been touched in *two* years.  That's not to say that it couldn't be complete and completely correct today, but I'm sure there are other syntax highlighters that have been released in that time, and they aren't there.

As for the deletion, it had been closed for a bit, and given that no effort was put into reopening it, or even a request to reopen so it could be edited, it was deleted.

I understand that there are other examples of these questions on Stack Overflow.  If you see them, you should vote to close them, and flag them for moderator attention if there aren't enough views on the question to get enough close votes, as we'll close them for you.