# Deleting suggestions posted as answers when they are implemented: Is this problematic?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, list-questions, spanish-stackoverflow

On Meta Stack Overflow en Español we have some practices that I would like to know if there other child Metas that use them, but particularly if those practices could eventually become problematic.

To make this question specific, I will refer the practice used on [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/65) (Warnings on potentially problematic questions), which is a [list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/289691). The practice in focus is as follows:

> The "question" describe the warning feature and give instructions to suggest a new warning *by posting an answer*. Once a suggested warning is implemented the corresponding answer is deleted and the question is updated by the OP who is a ♦ valuate associate (employee and diamond moderator).

The "problem" with the above approach is that the deleted answers and the corresponding voting scores are hidden for <10k rep users, and perhaps the "worse" part is losing child meta points, making harder to achieve the required points for per-site meta badges.

I think that the "orthodox way" is to have a *canonical question* for the instructions and highlighting exemplary cases but instead of posting the suggestions as answers, they should be posted as questions using [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), a specific "task" tag, and the status tags.

NOTES:

I think that I included the most important details here, so in order to participate in this discussion it's not necessary to be able to read Spanish. By the other hand, AFAIK all the users that participate regularly on the referred thread and other similar speak English, also the new Community Manager doesn't speak Spanish but he speaks English. I included a link to this question on a comment to the referred thread.

Some time ago, few users including me participated on the discussion of other *sui generis* practices on Meta Stack Overflow en Español chat but that practices appears to be abandoned. The one discussed here is "active", (my answer was deleted yesterday, 2018-12-18)

Mainly I posted this here to get feedback from others that have experience on implementing *sui generis* practices on other child meta sites.

Comment: It probably makes the most sense to discuss this on that per site meta, rather than here, if the moderation unique to that site is doing something that you consider problematic.  Seems all the more important for a non-English site, as a discussion on the topic here isn't going to be understandable to many users of a non-English speaking site.

Comment: I edited the question to add some clarification notes

Comment: Listening about this on meta.se is a bit frustrating to me. I will undelete the answers (to handle the issue at hand) and stop accepting new requests on that particular question. I will defer to the elected mods on how to move forward.

Comment: done, all the implemented answers have been undeleted :)

Comment: @g3rv4 I'm sorry that you feel frustrated. As an experiment it's fine, maybe the answer to this question is that the same or other similar practices are done on other child metas as it's not problematic at all or the benefits are such that these practices should be promoted in general not only on Meta es.so / across international-sites.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common practice. In Spanish SE we do it regularly on Meta for [some questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674), based on Server Fault's: [What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/200076). The key idea here is that a given post (the question or a canonical, accepted answer) keeps absorbing the information from the deleted answers, so no real information is lost apart from some specific details that are not that relevant.

Also, this makes it easier for folks to:

- Know what the new suggestions are, without past ones collapsing the top positions.
- Keep track in a single place of what are the decisions taken place in a given topic.
- Know what the format of a suggestion should be like, since there are always some old ones with a small score that doesn't allow them to be eligible for "graduating" yet.

Of course I agree that posting different questions would also be useful, but I think it makes the process less intuitive and needs from an extra effort of people to canonise the requests.

> deleted answers and the corresponding voting scores are hidden for <10k rep users

If the rules are clear enough, the reputation is not relevant once the answer is selected as "valid" to be fulfilled. If you indicate that it needs a certain score, it is obvious that any deleted answer will at least have that number.

> perhaps the "worse" part is losing child meta points, making harder to achieve the required points for per-site meta badges.

In my experience, people proposing these things are normally those that are quite active in Meta, so losing some +5 is not going to make much difference on the long run because they already have many other answers. Also, what is the benefit of getting more reputation of a suggestion once it is already implemented, if its rules already indicate that a certain threshold makes them eligible?

So far, I think this approach has been extremely welcomed in Stack Overflow en español.

Comment: Do you know if ♦ moderators delete answers that were merged on the canonical answer on [sf] y [spanish.se]? Do you know is there a * canonical question* about handling [tag:list-questions] on those sites or the rules are set on each [tag:list-questions]?

Comment: @Rubén about deletion: in Spanish.SE it is normally we ♦ moderators who delete those answers. In [sf] I don't know who does it, but the rules are clear about it _Delete content that has been merged into the official list. Try to keep this post neat and tidy_. About a canonical question: in Spanish.SE we don't have it, we normally establish the "rules" in the specific question we are working on. In [sf] I don't know.