# Proposal: badge immunity for community wiki

Tags: feature-request

Many very interesting discussions are not just closed, but locked by the moderator. In my opinion, the best argument against leaving such discussions open is provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56745/151996).

One of the ideas proposed in the page I linked to is badge immunity for community wikis. It would, hopefully, remove a significant reason for starting frivolous discussions, and hence reduce the necessity of closing/locking interesting, though slightly off-topic, discussions.

Is there any support for this proposal?

Comment: I'd rather see *discussions* deleted than encouraged.

Comment: The only badges you can't get for community wiki posts are *tag badges*.

Comment: That's strange. It seemed like there was some support for this idea.

Comment: @max You linked to a post that's almost 2 years old, things have changed...

Comment: @Yahoo Answers Enthusiast ah haha now I understand.. no wonder. I didn't realize 2 years is enough to cause a major change in opinion

Comment: @max Are you kidding me? On Meta Stack Overflow it takes seconds to cause a major change in opinion ;P Seriously now, 2 years is a long time on the internet, we really don't like these questions anymore because we've seen them fail again and again.

Comment: These days on meta 9 out of 10 question got downvotes,flags and even most of them are closed. The simple reason is that every question is a repeated one,people ask question without research and their question is closed.So i think nothing wrong in this.I am also realized it importance now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As reported in [The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), Community Wiki should not be used for frivolous discussions, joke, or fun questions. If somebody asks one of those questions nowadays, the question should be closed, not made Community Wikis.

When Community Wiki posts are legitimate, I don't see any reason why a user who posted an answer with a score of 10 should not get a badge. I don't also see any reason why a user who made a Community Wiki answer for a question that was not Community Wiki should not get any badge because that answer's score.