# Where should I post a question about software architecture?

Tags: support, specific-question, site-recommendation

I have a question about software architecture. I [have posted it on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917845/jsf-primefaces-spring-hibernate-mvc-development-guide).

Then the question got put on hold. Where should I post it?

Comment: It's not on hold as off-topic; it was unclear. Now it's still missing the actual exception you're getting.

Comment: @Mat that was not the question i have asked
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917845/jsf-primefaces-spring-hibernate-mvc-development-guide/17918742?noredirect=1#17918742
check this

Comment: Please edit this question to put the right link then.

Comment: @Mat already Did :)

Comment: I down voted your question because the reason for the hold is stated right there on the page and you didn't read it properly.

Comment: @slugster I asked where should i post such question.!! Not the reason

Comment: @Dileep: recommendations for resources are pretty much off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites. Some sites accept some forms of them, but usually with very strict criteria. That's just not the type of question the Stack Exchange Q&A model is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

For where to ask questions that are generally about software architecture, see [this previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181333/is-there-a-site-for-software-architecture-questions).

But I don't think your question falls in this category. It is on hold because most of the users don't understand what you trying to ask. In other words, it is unclear.

Comment: Aside from the lack of clarity, it also looks like this is a shopping-style recommendation question, which are explicitly disallowed across the network.