# Is writing "will upvote..." appropriate?

Tags: discussion, voting, edits, etiquette

Some questions contain statements like "will upvote everyone who provide valid code".
When hovering over the upvote icon of an answer, I see that SO believes it should be pressed for a "useful" answer.

I personally think writing sentences like the above imply that the writer is not going to respect SO rules about voting, and should be edited out, although I don't think I've ever seen sentences like that being edited out.

**Added:** Or is it that the original author can define what he finds useful?

Do you agree?

Comment: Do you have any examples of questions like this? I'm not sure if I've seen that before (but I'm not surprised it happens either).

Comment: I'll upvote anyone who can provide examples of this happening.

Comment: @Tim: 100% sure I saw it, but can't find anything specific right now.

Comment: @Grace Note, I would like one upvote please: ["I will 'upvote' every answer that even remotely assists me in making a decision."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180538/determining-whether-to-store-xml-data-as-xml-or-in-normalized-tables-in-sql-serve)

Comment: @Grace, heck, give me a second one: ["I will upvote any non-insane answer."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574068/how-do-you-deploy-your-wsgi-application-and-why-it-is-the-best-way)

Comment: @Popular Demand: Thanks for the examples (-:

Comment: @Grace,Popular: That's voting commerce right there (:

Comment: I will upvote anybody (in some other Meta question) who upvotes my answer. For a limited time only, there's even a 2 for 1 offer through my sock puppet account. Hurry!

Comment: @Pekka: Throw in a SO comment upvote and a small latte or the deal's off!

Comment: @Tim how about my sock puppet goes upvoting some old answers of yours. On the SOFU[E] site of your choice. Huh? Come on. I even make a condescending sidenote about low quality questions, it's not *that* hard to upvote.

Comment: @Tim: I think that's the first recorded voting blackmail in history

Comment: @Popular: Thanks for the edit and sorry for undoing it. Restored it now.

Comment: @Pekka: Well, it is true that all those `mod_rewrite` answers could use more attention...Alright, I'm game. Just give me some time to write a Greasemonkey script to click the upvote button on your answer, so I can have plausible deniability.

Comment: @Oren A: Some like to bribe people with votes, I like to extort votes out of them. Such is the world... But no, to actually say something of value, I do agree with your point. People should upvote answers only if they contribute in a significant way to resolving the question, and they shouldn't feel like "promising" votes is going to influence the number/quality/whatever of answers they get.

Comment: That's a very seductive offer by @Pekka, but the *real* question is, does it work the other way round? Let's see! For a limited time only, I will be posting comments that will be upvoted by everybody but Pekka (or his puppet)! Hurry! This exclusive deal won't last forever!

Comment: @Oren, no worries, I haven't even been on the site for the past several hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crass and graceless.

That said, there are few answers to *my* questions that I have not voted for. Broad-based voting for people who take a credible crack at my trouble is just good manners. It's the explicit announcement that comes over badly.

Answer (score 8):

Good point. It's definitely not good style.

Usually, the question will be in the same vein.

I find it okay to edit stuff like this out.

Comment: Don't edit it out. Just replace "upvote" with "downvote".

Comment: @Henk ahahahahahaha!

Comment: @Henk "*I will downvote useful answers. I will downvote unhelpful answers. I will accept the most downvoted answer.*"

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to "thanks in advance": both promise to not actually consider whether your answer is useful or helpful, and possibly to not even read it at all.

I remember this kind of "upvote promise" being used more on poll/[discussion-list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason) questions than other types, and those don't fit very well in the first place.  This combination points to a general misunderstanding, even though the "useful" criteria is certainly subjective and interpreted broadly.

Comment: IMO "thanks in advance" is just good manners.

Comment: @Oren: I find it incredibly rude, but, particularly from non-native speakers, I understand it wasn't intended that way.

Comment: @Gnome: Full disclosure: I use it a lot (I'm not native speaker). should I stop doing that? (-:

Comment: I always consider "Thanks in advance" to actually mean "Thanks in advance for your time." Which is completely valid, irrespective of the quality of the answer, since the answerer decided to spend a finite resource on an attempt to help you.

Comment: @Gnome: I'm curious. I'm a native English speaker. I find "thanks in advance" to be mostly unnecessary, and certainty unneeded in SE questions, but for I don't see rudeness at all. Where is that coming from?

Comment: @Oren: My position should be clear: don't. :)  At best, it's unnecessary and redundant in SE questions.  If you really want to encourage more/better answers and show appreciation for those taking the time to read your post, spend time writing a [better](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) [question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @Michael: "...the phrase 'Thanks in advanvce!' has become a thin veil for 'I'm feigning being polite because in reality I don't want to take the time to properly thank you when I should so I'll just ask and thank you all at once so I don't have to be inconvenienced by properly expressing my appreciation later, when I should. This is really more convenient for me.'" as [one person](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080221132215AAG5yc8) put [it](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22thanks+in+advance%22+rude).

Comment: @Peter: "It is clearly a tactic and not sincere since it can be observed that very few posters that use those phrases express gratefulness AFTER they have got an answer." — [Peter Mortensen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64649/is-writing-will-upvote-appropriate/64673#64673)

Answer (score 1):

No, writing “will upvote” is not appropriate. It is just one more way to try to get preferential treatment.

Other kindergarten-like behaviour of this sort is "Please help me", "Extremely urgent" and "thanks in advance". It is common on forums, but has the same origin: scream higher than the others or beg to get attention.

It is clearly a tactic and not sincere since it can be observed that very few posters that use those phrases express gratefulness AFTER they have got an answer.

Comment: +1 for everything except "thanks in advance" - that mostly is just an expression of friendliness really

Comment: @Pekka: you might be correct about "thanks in advance". It is also what Eric Raymond writes in [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#courtesy). But I have my doubts.

Comment: Even ESR notes a large caveat with "thanks in advance"; plus what he currently recommends, which reads as "thanks for your time *already* spent", isn't "in advance".

Answer (score 1):

I think that there's too many questions with answers that aren't upvoted. I've seen  occasions where an answer is useful to the questioner based on the comments they put in the answer, yet there's no upvote. I wonder how many people think they're voting for the *best* answer?

So, advertising "I ain't one of them one question, one vote people" is ok, but there certainly is a point at which you're being, um, too easy.

Comment: +1 totally agree. I think this is a real problem on SO. Far too many good answers (well, at least helpful and/or useful answers) aren't getting any upvotes.