# Sharing a question between different SE sites

Tags: support, asking-questions

If I have got a question that can be asked on different sites I have to choose just one.

For example, I've just asked on `unix.SE` this question:

> [most Mac-compatible linux distribution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/most-mac-compatible-linux-distribution)

I believe that I can ask just the same question on `apple.SE` site. But I don't think that it is polite.

So the idea is to make it possible to share questions between sites. Maybe it will be topics with different colors or topics in special section on site that will redirect to original topic on original site.

I am sure that here is many questions on main SO site wich can be discussed with `Programmers` and with `CodeReview` and even `ServerFault` guys.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think such a "let's make a list of the best X" questions are allowed on one site, much less more than one.

[Should we have a "List of X" close reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason)

So.. no.

Comment: It is not about my particular question

Comment: @fl00r - the issue is is that your question is off topic **for all** SE sites, not that it *could* be posted on many,

Comment: @fl00r the reason you think your question may apply to more than one site *is because it is a bad question*.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think so. It is just about iMac driver support in different distributions. That's all. Also my this topic is not just about my question, but there is a bunch of questions wich can be posted at many sites.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, It can be a bad question, but what if there is a good question that can be shared between sites?

Comment: @fl00r I think it would be wise to come up with a good example of a *good* question that would benefit to be shared between sites, if you want to support such.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is better to avoid to post the same questions on different SE sites.
You could be interested in different aspects of the question, and in this case I think it's acceptable to ask the question in different SE sites, if the question is being tailored to the site where the question is being asked.
If you ask the question using the same exact words for both the sites, then I think it's not acceptable; in that case, I would suggest to choose the site where you want to post the question, and post it. Posting the same question on more sites just to have more chances to get an answer is not acceptable, from my point of view.