# Is a "List of X" without "best" still inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, not-constructive

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730308/list-of-ruby-vms was closed as not constructive.

The OP had done their homework and listed the ones he'd found (15).

The question didn't ask for people to say which VM was better than any other, just which VMs exist, so it wasn't subjective or argumentative. Subjective and argumentative was given as a problem with "List of X" in [Should we have a "List of X" close reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason)

Is a "List of X" that doesn't mention anything subjective still inappropriate?

Comment: You'll have to excuse me, I see no use in being anything but blunt. Some questions just have no place on SO, and that one seems to fit the bill quite nicely.

Comment: Does anybody ever ask for a "worst list of X"? "Best" is almost always implied even if not explicitly stated.

Comment: @AnnaLear: That's not a common question but [it has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329) (at its core).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **not constructive**
>
> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers
> to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this
> question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **[polling](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)**, or
> extended discussion.

Comment: How is it a poll?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm ["the only time you really know you’re looking at a poll is when you see those one-line *answers*"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) such as "X is a Ruby VM".

Comment: @Andrew, the community has chosen (correctly in most cases, I believe), to see  "poll" as synonymous with "survey".

Comment: "Is it always the fault of the questioner that the answers suck? Do they deserve all the blame for the fact that people with nothing useful to say want to participate anyway and bring their reddit-style “tweets” into the answers?" - it's not you, it's me. :(

Comment: These kinds of questions attract suck answers.  That's part of the reason they're not constructive.

Comment: Another reason is that many such "lists" are not guaranteed to be complete at any point in time, but rather include only the "best" or "most familiar" instances, which is why they are "not a good fit to our Q&A format."

Comment: Where is the correct place for the "community" to discuss this and for members of the community to vote they disagree?

Comment: You're in the right place, @studgeek; Meta is meant for this kind of discussion. You may be on the right page, as a matter of fact, depending on what argument you want to put forward. Be sure to look around first, though - chances are what you want to talk about has been discussed before.