# "closed as not constructive" is an abused reason to close a question

Tags: discussion, rant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a “List of X” without “best” still inappropriate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109067/is-a-list-of-x-without-best-still-inappropriate)

I come across many questions which got closed because of this reason "closed as not constructive". I find it an annoying choice to close a question when the question seems beneficial, specially when the question gets a lot of upvotes and the accepted answer gets also several upvotes.

Today I was looking for any useful visualizers for Visual Studio. I Googled, searched CodePlex, GitHub, CodeProject, Visual Studio Gallery and came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862321/useful-visualizers-for-visual-studio) on SO. A 2009 question which got closed 3 months ago. So after about 3 years, I don't see any debates, I don't see any arguments, I don't see any polling and I don't see and extended discussion!

So what is the problem exactly? It's annoying to see the same people (I am familiar with some names because I came across them many times in the past) who can't leave something which can be useful in peace.

And if someone knows and used some tools (visualizers in this case), can they be considered to have a specific expertise.

Even if I spend hours searching the web, SO could be a place where one can find a hidden gem which is unknown to most people.

Comment: The question says "Are there any other useful visualizers out there?" There's no right answer, which means it textbook "not constructive"

Comment: The question is what is commonly known as a "shopping question". There is no right or best answer that can truly be given for questions like this as it depends highly on the circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

See [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog post as well.

The issues with recommendation qs are:

- They are generally localized in time -- they become invalid after a few months or so
- They end up with a lot of equally valid answers

Btw, there is an "or" in the  `solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion`. By "polling", we mean that you get a lot of answers that then basically are chosen via voting.

Comment: I don't agree with everything in the FAQ, hence the rant. So quoting the faq doesn't help me. Answers are localized in time if they are good only for a few days or weeks. That's not the case with many questions. For example no one ever claims a .NET 1.1 specific question too localized, yet most people don't use it anymore. I have many more examples. Your second point gives me an idea for another rant which I will post soon.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - Whether or not you agree with the FAQ is irrelevant. If you want shopping-type recommendations, then go elsewhere. It's that simple.

Comment: @Manishearth Yes there's an "or" and the answers didn't create ANY of  those concerns... even after 3 years.

Comment: @Jack Not shopping.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - [Yes, shopping.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) Again, if you don't like it, leave. It really is that simple.

Comment: @tony it was closed. Of course the q didn't get many answers. It can't. But the _type_ of question was asking for("solicits") equally valid recommendations ("polling"). That is considered as NC here. That's it. Nitpicking the in-short close reason won't help.